# ignite cluster and kubernetes integration

Tags: ignite

I am new to Ignite.

## Test1: (without Kubernetes)

step1: I installed Ignite 2.6.0 in 2 VMs (ubuntu), started node in one VM. with below comand.
bin/ignite.sh examples/config/example-ignite.xml

step2: All my configurations are in example-default.xml

step3: Executed client.jar, which contains datagrid logic , in other VM ( This VM is client as well as node).

step4: Able to store data in cache.

## Test2: (Kubernetes installed in cloud)

step1: Followed steps mentioned in url, https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/stateful-deployment.

1. Run all commands of 'RBAC Authorization' and 'Ignite Servie' hyperlink yamls as is.
2. Next in section 'Same storage for the database and WAL files', run 'ignite-stateful-set.yaml'
3. CONFIG_URI in ignite-stateful-set.yaml is pointng to 'example-default.xml (renamed)' of 'Kubernetes IP Finder' section.
4. Added IPs of 2 VMs in example-default.xml 'addresses' section of TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder bean.

Step2: Copied 'example-default.xml' in /opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bv-in/examples/config(where ignite installed) of 2 VMs.

Step3: Now I started the same client.jar which is giving the exception (attached)
command to run client is attached
(Kubernetes and Ignite installation are in same VM(ubuntu))

Please let me know anything wrong in Test2. Thanks in advance.

## example-default.xml

```xml
     <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
            <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
    
            <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
            <property name="includeEventTypes">
                <list>
                    
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>
    
                    
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
                </list>
            </property>
    
           
        <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="40"/>
        <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="30"/>
    
         <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                             <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                                     <list>
                                             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                                             <!-- Custom region name. -->
                                             <property name="name" value="6GB_Region"/>
    
                                             <!-- 100 MB initial size. -->
                                             <property name="initialSize" value="#{100L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
    
                                             <!-- 6 GB maximum size. -->
                                             <property name="maxSize" value="#{6L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
    
                                             <!-- Enabling persistence for the region. -->
                                             <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                                             <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                                            </bean>
                                     </list>
                             </property>
                     </bean>
        </property>
    
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
             <bean id="myCacheTemplate" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                     <property name="dataRegionName" value="6GB_Region"/>
                     <property name="name" value="myCache"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                     <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                     <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                     <property name="copyOnRead" value="false"/>
                                     <property name="rebalanceBatchSize" value="#{1024 * 1024}"/>
                                     <property name="rebalanceThrottle" value="0"/>
                                     <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="4"/>
                                    <!-- <property name="swapEnabled" value="false"/> 
                                     <property name="startSize" value="#{100 * 1024 * 1024}"/> 
                    <property name="evictionPolicy">
                             
                             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                             
                             <property name="maxSize" value="1000000"/>
                             </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="0"/>-->
             </bean>
             </list>
        </property>
    
    
            <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <!--
                            Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                            instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                            to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                        -->
                        <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
               <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                        <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                        <property name="serviceName" value="ignite"/>
                        <!-- <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                   <value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500</value>
                                    <value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500</value>                                
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                        <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                    <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                        </bean>-->
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

## Code Snippet:

```java
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
        //try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("D:\\ApacheIgnite\\apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin\\examples\\config\\example-ignite.xml")) {

            
            ignite.cluster().active(true);
            System.out.println(">>> Cache asynchronous API started.");

            

            // Auto-close cache at the end of the example.
            try (IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache")) {
                
               Collection<IgniteFuture<?>> futs = new ArrayList<>();

                // Execute several puts asynchronously.
               String key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
               String value = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
              
               System.out.println("CAME HERE 11"); 
               
               long put_start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
               // Execute several puts asynchronously.
               for(int i=0;i<messageCount;i++) {
                  
                 futs.add(cache.putAsync(key+String.valueOf(i), value));
                  
               }        
               long put_end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
               
               System.out.println("Time taken to put="+(put_end_time-put_start_time)+" Milli Seconds ");

              key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
              long get_start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
              
              // Wait for completion of all futures.
              for (IgniteFuture<?> fut : futs) fut.get();
              
              
              
              // Execute get operation asynchronously and wait for result.
              for(int i=0;i<messageCount;i++) {
                  cache.getAsync(key+String.valueOf(i)).listen(new IgniteInClosure<IgniteFuture<String>>() {
    
                      /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2066693655303313807L;

                    @Override
                      public void apply(IgniteFuture<String> fut) {
                          //System.out.println("Get operation completed [value=" + fut.get() + ']');
                      }
                  });
              }
              
              long get_end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
              System.out.println("Time taken to get="+(get_end_time-get_start_time)+" Milli Seconds ");
              
              
              // Get the metrics of all the data regions configured on a node.
              Collection<DataRegionMetrics> regionsMetrics = ignite.dataRegionMetrics();
              System.out.println("----------------------------------Data Region Metrics---------------------------------- ");         
              // Print out some of the metrics.
              for (DataRegionMetrics metrics : regionsMetrics) {
                  
                  System.out.println(">>> Memory Region Name: " + metrics.getName());
                  System.out.println(">>> Allocation Rate: " + metrics.getAllocationRate());
                  System.out.println(">>> Fill Factor: " + metrics.getPagesFillFactor());
                  System.out.println(">>> Allocated Size: " + metrics.getTotalAllocatedSize());
                  System.out.println(">>> Physical Memory Size: " + metrics.getPhysicalMemorySize());
                  System.out.println(">>> Total allocated Size: " + metrics.getTotalAllocatedSize());                 
                  System.out.println(">>> Eviction Rate: " + metrics.getEvictionRate());                  
                  System.out.println(">>> Off Heap Size: " + metrics.getOffHeapSize());
                  System.out.println(">>> Off Heap used Size: " + metrics.getOffheapUsedSize());
                  
              }
              
              
              System.out.println("Cached size=="+cache.size(CachePeekMode.ALL));
              ignite.compute().broadcast(()->System.out.println(cache.get("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0")));
              //cache.removeAll();
              cache.clear();
              //cache.removeAllAsync();
              System.out.println("Cached size1=="+cache.size(CachePeekMode.ALL));
            
            }
            finally {
                // Distributed cache could be removed from cluster only by #destroyCache() call.
                //ignite.destroyCache("myCache");
            }
        }
```

## ignite-stateful-set.yaml

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
      name: ignite
      namespace: ignite
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: ignite
      serviceName: ignite
      replicas: 2
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: ignite
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: ignite
          containers:
          - name: ignite
            image: apacheignite/ignite:2.6.0
            env:
            - name: OPTION_LIBS
              value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
            - name: selfLink
              value: file:///opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-default.xml
            - name: IGNITE_QUIET
              value: "false"
            - name: JVM_OPTS
              value: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
            ports:
            - containerPort: 11211 # JDBC port number.
            - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port number.
            - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port number.
            - containerPort: 49112 # JMX port number.
            - containerPort: 10800 # SQL port number.
            - containerPort: 8080 # REST port number.
            - containerPort: 10900 #Thin clients port number.
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/data/ignite"
              name: ignite-storage
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: ignite-storage
        spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi
```

## Observations after starting the client.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:990)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:355)

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite.cfg$child#0' defined in URL [file:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#c038203' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] while setting bean property 'discoverySpi'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#c038203' defined in URL 

[file:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-default.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#c038203' defined in URL [file:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-default.xml]: Cannot create inner bean

[file:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-default.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder
```

**Other form of the question ...**

Once the Kubernetes is up as per the steps mentioned above with say 2 pods, how and where to deploy my ignite data-grid logic client.jar file to execute java file inside.

**@clarification**

** Below file ...

- name: selfLink
  value: file:///opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-default.xml

should contain only below content **

```xml
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
        <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
      </bean>
```

**and file

try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/examples/config/example-ignite.xml"))
contains my custom configurations as below

```xml
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                    <property name="serviceName" value="ignite"/>
                    <bean 
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500</value>
                                <value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500</value>                                
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
```

**And the below tags will help Kubernetes Cluster to identify Ignite cluster nodes. I can start running my client.**

property name="namespace" value="ignite"
property name="serviceName" value="ignite

Please correct if this is not the right approach

**@ client-running**

```bash
java -Xms5g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -cp "/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-shmem-1.0.0.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/cache-api-1.0.0.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/annotations-13.0.jar
:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-core-2.6.0.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/lucene-queryparser-5.5.2.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/lucene-core-5.5.2.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.2.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/ignite-indexing-2.6.0.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/h2-1.4.195.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-jdbc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-expression-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/ignite-spring-2.6.0.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/optional/ignite-kubernetes.jar:/opt/apache-ignite-fabric-2.6.0-bin/libs/apache-ignite.jar" com.ecoenergy.cortix.ignite.IgniteFutureAsync 1000000
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to how you format your question. Make sure that all code is in the code section. It is kinda hard to make sense of it now.

Answer (score 1):

You must not have `addresses` for `TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder`. Because of that the system can't create it from XML. Remove the `addresses` section.

Comment: Stanislav Lukyanov - I added @clarification section to my question. Please let me know if that is the right approach

Comment: I removed address for TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder. Made the configuration changes as mentioned in clarification section of the question. And started client as mentioned in the section 'client running' of the question. **Getting error** - Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'namespace' of bean class [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder

Comment: You need to use either `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` or `TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder`. Note that the former doesn't have the `namespace` and `serviceName` properties, and the latter doesn't have `addresses`.